# How to check if at least one ordering of the given row matches one of the rows of a table?

Tags: syntax, conditional

Consider some list of elements

```
elements={"a","k",1,"12","cdt","b","m","l","q",132,12.345,999,1000,Exp[x^2],Sin[y]};
```

We may make the following table

```
tabb = Table[Take[RandomSample[elements],4],50]
```

and a row

```
roww = Take[RandomSample[elements],4]
```

I have to check if `roww` matches at least one row of `tab`, now taking into account that the ordering of the elements of `roww` is not important. I.e., if `tabb` includes the row `{999,1000,Exp[x^2],Sin[y]}`, while `roww` is `{1000,Sin[y],999,Exp[x^2]}` then the decision should be `True`.

How to check if at least one ordering of `roww` matches with at least one row of `tabb`?

**Edit**

Probably it is `ContainsOnly`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MemberQ[Sort /@ tabb, Sort[roww]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
containsInAnyOrder = Not @ FreeQ[{OrderlessPatternSequence @@ #2}] @ # &;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[roww], tabb]
```

Some examples

```
tabb = {{"m", Sin[y], "q", "k"}, {"q", "cdt", "m", 132}, {"12", "a", "m", "b"}, {"k", 999, 12.345`, 132}};

roww = {132, "m", "q", "cdt"};

Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[roww], tabb]
```

True

```
roww = {132, "q", "q", "cdt"};

Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[roww], tabb]
```

True

```
roww = {132, "q", "-1", "cdt"};

Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[roww], tabb]
```

False

Answer (score 1):

My attempt is as follows:

```
MatchesRowQ[table_, row_] := MemberQ[table, #] & /@ 
                             Permutations[row, Length[row]] // Or @@ # &
```

Testing `MatchesRowQ`:

```
tabb = {{"m", Sin[y], "q", "k"}, {"q", "cdt", "m", 132},
        {"12", "a", "m", "b"}, {"k", 999, 12.345`, 132}};

roww = {132, "m", "q", "cdt"};

MatchesRowQ[tabb, roww]

(*True*)
```